# Is it possible to get a formula for this summation

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

> The binomial sum
>   $$s_n=\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n+1}{1}+\binom{n+2}{2}+\cdots+\binom{2n}{n}$$

I tried solving through recurrence, but unable to find one.

Comment: Shouldn't the last term in the summation be $(2n,n)$ and not $(2n-1,n)$?

Comment: yes, my mistake

Comment: Try some small $n$'s. Do you have a conjecture about the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the difference $\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n-1}{k-1} + \binom{n-1}{k}$. You should get $\binom{2n}{n}$ if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Use this relation, and find $S_n - S_{n-1}$, it is simple.